# Installing GLPK

Tags: gnu, glpk

I'm following [this](http://winglpk.sourceforge.net/) link for installing GLPK which I intend to use to conduct some optimization. When I've downloaded GLPK, and added

```
 C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```

to PATH for environment variables and try to execute one of the example files (even by opening the cmd window in the file where the test file is located) by doing

```
 glpsol --model assign.mod
```

It says that

```
glpsol is not a internal command, external command, program or command file.
```

When I open the command in the win64 folder (a subfolder of glpk) then I can do:

```
 glpsol.exe --help
```

and get information. I can also see the glpsol programfile in the folder. However when I try to open a model somewhere on my computer it does'nt recognize glpsol. Isn't that why you add System32 into your PATH?

In the guide it says that

*...Therefore it is suggested to copy the DLLs to %SystemRoot%nsystem32*.

Is this something that you must do? Which are these DLLs? Can you do this using a command in the cmd file? I thinking that including System32 into the path does this?

I've added SysWOW64 into the path due to me using 64 Bit Windows 7. Not sure if it is the way to go though.

Hope someone can shed some light into this!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

To use glpsol outside of the dedicated folder you have to put the relevant files somewhere, where your System can recognize them (somewhere in the defined Path Environment)

The "DLLs" are just the glpk_X_XX.dll, for 64bit systems use the dll in the w64 folder and put it in the SysWOW64. Now your System will find the dll - but still not glpsol. Just copy the glpsol.exe in system32 for that, and voilà your done.

Adding the GLPK Directory to the Environment Path should also work.